# Microsoft CRM could not log you on to the system. Make sure your user record

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-3

"Microsoft CRM could not log you on to the system. Make sure your user record is enabled and that you have been assigned at least one security role. For more information, contact your system administrator."

When I RDP into the server and try Microsoft CRM Workflow Manager/Monitor with http or https connectivity, it doesn't work. "The specified Microsoft CRM server is not responding. This might happen if it is currently unavaliable, it is not a Microsoft CRM server, or you are not a valid user. Contact your sys-admin."

This is a Microsoft CRM v3.0 / Microsoft SQL server 2005 box, Active directory is on a seperate box..

When I right click Microsoft CRM Worlkflow Service, properties, log on: it shows "crmtestuser" and a password. I did not RDP or try logging in as that crmtestuser, but I am Admin... Could this be a clue?

What can I try?

Comment: This question sounds like it belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Does the user that you're logging onto the machine have an account in CRM?  If so, does that account have any security roles assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

Also, in CRM 3.0, there are special permissions given to the user that installed CRM. If you can't give permissions to the a user because you can access CRM, try using the same user that installed CRM, and with that user logged in, give Administrator permissions to other users.